# I want to encode and store the address variable and the uint256 variable

Tags: ether, keccak

I am currently using it as follows.

```
bytes memory _byte = abi.encode(ca, tokenId);
```

I learned that this method can take different variables and produce the same results.

If I use the keccak256 function, I can prevent it, but I can't decode it.

Is there a way to have a unique value by encoding and decoding variables without using keccak256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract EncodeVars {

    bytes public _bytes;

    function encodeVars(address _addr, uint _num) external returns (bytes memory) {
        _bytes = abi.encode(_addr, _num);
        return _bytes;
    }

    function decodeVars() external view returns (address _addr, uint _num) {
        (_addr, _num) = abi.decode(_bytes, (address, uint));
    }

}
```

You're right not to use keccak256 as yes, that would give you a hash of the values.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But what I'm curious about is how you can combine multiple variables into one and keep their values unique. I know that the "abi.encode()" function can take a different input and make the same output, but am I mistaken? 
The reference is the following link:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113188/can-abi-encode-receive-different-values-and-return-the-same-result